# Slide Toggle After Page Resize Bugging - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a collapsible navigation which works fine on page load, but on the resizing of the window it seems to get trippy and slides up and down a number of times (can be just twice, or can go on for up to ten times).

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.myfunction = function () {
    $(".navi-btn").hide();    
    $(".navigation").show();
};
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
$.fn.mysecondfunction = function () {
    $(".navi-btn").show();
    $(".navigation").hide();
    $(".navi-btn").click(function () {
        $(".navigation").slideToggle();
    });
    $("li").click(function () {
        $(".navigation").slideToggle();
    });
    $("#width").text("too small");
};
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function () {
var width = $(window).width();
if (width > 400) {
    $('#width').myfunction();
} else {
    $('#width').mysecondfunction();
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width > 400) {
        $('#width').myfunction();
    } else {
        $('#width').mysecondfunction();
    }

   });
 });
```

Here is a "working" demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wj6E3/)

I have written the script myself, so I am sure there is an easy fix, I just don't seem to know what I have done.

I was thinking perhaps after a resize, would reloading the function be a good workaround, and if so how can this effect be achieved?

Comment: That links returns a 404 error

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Wj6E3/) Better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the click event while resizing the window. This will bind the same function multiple times to the click event. So the best option would be to bind the event only once which could be done on ready event. In this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Wj6E3/2/) I limited this binding in resize event itself by adding a class to the navi-btn and checking that.

```
$(".navi-btn").not(".binded").addClass("binded").click(function () {
    $(".navigation").slideToggle();
});
```

Hope this gives you an idea.

Thanks,

Jothi

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick test and found that removing the `resive` condition and putting it into it's own function seemd to fix the issue

From

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var width = $(window).width();
if (width > 400) {
    $('#width').myfunction();
} else {
    $('#width').mysecondfunction();
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width > 400) {
        $('#width').myfunction();
    } else {
        $('#width').mysecondfunction();
    }

   });
 });
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width > 400) {
        $('#width').myfunction();
    } else {
        $('#width').mysecondfunction();
    }
});
$(window).resize(function () {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width > 400) {
            $('#width').myfunction();
        } else {
            $('#width').mysecondfunction();
        }

    });
```